# How to share a mustache template between Scalate and Javascript?

Tags: scala, mustache, scalatra, scalate

So I'm using some server-side mustache templates with Scalatra and Scalate, and I'd like to use them in my Javascript code too.

Ideally I can load the same templates via some sort of ajax call, but I'm not really sure how to set that up with Scalatra + jetty.

Currently the templates live in

> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/views/

This is the default for Scalatra, but those files aren't served statically by jetty, so I'm unsure how to share them with the front end.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can make them statically available by putting them in a directory under webapp.  If your jetty's context is "joe" and the webapp directory is "henry" then you should be able to get at a "something.mustache" with "joe/henry/something.mustache".  Check out the "Serving static files" section [here](http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/project-structure.html).

Comment: @n0741337 So presumably there's also some sort of configuration I can set with Scalate that tell it to look in that location for templates instead of WEB-INF?

Comment: `layoutTemplate` will allow that, but the mustache's compiled parent directory seems to still be under the control of Scalatra and didn't have the time to read their source.  I ended up using relative paths for some `<script>` and `<css>` links with "../../" to get back to webapp.  If you don't have other file dependencies like that, then it will probably just work.  `mustache( ..., "layout" -> <webapp path> )` might work too, but I haven't tried that(look [here](http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/guides/views/scalate.html)).

Comment: Ah! Got you, excellent, I'll play around with that function instead.